# Using SASS to check ancestor/parent elements with &

Tags: css, sass, frontend

I'm still getting to grips with SASS. I want to check within a selector whether or not an element is within a certain other ancestor/parent element.

I have this:

```
p.key-name {
    float: left;
    padding: 4px 32px 0 2px;
}

li:last-of-type p.key-name {
    padding-right: 0;
}
```

Works great, but is regular CSS so no surprise there. But I'd rather have that second selector grouped within the first, so I tried this:

```
p.key-name {
    float: left;
    padding: 4px 32px 0 2px;

    li:last-of-type & {
        padding-right: 0;
    }
}
```

That doesn't work. I can see why by looking at the processed CSS, but I'm wondering if there's a way of using SASS to make this notion work.

Thanks for any help offered!

**Edit:** As explored in the comments, it turns out that the code works but there's a parent `<li>` higher up the hierarchy interfering due to a lack of specificity in the SASS (i.e. no class or anything more qualifying on the `li:last-of-type`). So the two snippets above are in fact equivalent _as long as there are no `<li>`s surrounding these ones.

Comment: Not sure to have understood: you sass code works as expected (tested on sassmeister with v.3.2.19)

Comment: ok I was wrong, if you check here it indeed should work as expected: http://thesassway.com/intermediate/referencing-parent-selectors-using-ampersand

Comment: Which Sass version are you using?

Comment: Cannot reproduce.  Code produces the desired results in all versions of Sass that can be tested with on [Sassmeister](http://sassmeister.com/).

Comment: Thanks guys. It might be something else but the two snippets don't have parity in my set-up (SASS 3.3). It looks like the & selector _is_ applied using the second snippet — so I was wrong about that — but it applies to all of the `<li>`s rather than just the last, whereas the first snippet correctly targets just the final `<li>`. I'll continue exploring. This is the markup format by the way: http://jsfiddle.net/RyanJW/80s27yLw/

Comment: Still cannot reproduce: http://sassmeister.com/gist/5f2409bcb69d77267555

Comment: Your code is perfectly valid. Can we have the whole code? (What's the processed CSS in your case? Is it nested in other Sass code? Are you using libraries?)

Comment: Ah man, OK I just figured it out. I'm working in a partial and there's another `<li>` much further up the hierarchy that wraps around everything. So the SASS is indeed correct, but due to a lack of specificity was taking appropriate `<li>`s into account. Thanks for establishing that my SASS was actually correct, otherwise I might have spent ages focusing on the wrong issue.